# How to customise bundle product options block (change option renderer)

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, bundled-product

I've to customise the bundle product options block. The default xml structure used by Magento is:

```
<action method="addRenderer">
<type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block>
</action>
```

Blocks are declared without any names, so I guess the `remove` tag doesn't work. How to remove a block from the layout xml? I tried to set a name, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify end result you're going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `addRenderer()` method:

```
/**
 * Add renderer for an option type, e.g., select, radio button, etc.
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $block
 */
public function addRenderer($type, $block)
{
    $this->_optionRenderers[$type] = $block;
}
```

This means, if you call it again for a given type, it replaces the existing renderer:

```
<action method="addRenderer">
    <type>select</type>
    <block>your_module/your_select_renderer</block>
</action>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'm now able to use different blocks using different product_bundle_type handles!